# How to check if a string is in a text file or not, if yes then show the text above that string in text file?

Tags: c#, string

For example:

User puts the string ***"Hello"*** then the program will check the file **program.txt** to check if the string Hello exists or not. If yes, then show the line above the string Hello in program.txt:

> **program.txt file**
>
> 123456
>
> Hello

The program will show the string ***123456***

So how can I do this in C#? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sounds a lot like homework. What have you tried

Comment: It's not a homework, I just try to do this but I can't. I know how to find a string in text file but I don't know how to show the line above

Comment: You can open the file as a stream, than you read the file line by line while keeping the previous line in a variable.  Once you find the word on the current line, you just have to print the saved variable.

Comment: @jsucupira Can you show me more about the code, please?

Comment: what should the program do if the first line is Hello?

Comment: @Benj Then the program should return a message box

Comment: @Viettungvuong this does looks like home work.  So I won't post code, but you may find this useful. https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+read+file+line+by+line

Comment: @jscupira I swear this it not a homework. But ok thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like an homework !!
a very naive way to do it ,also for big size txt files this will not be the way to do,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool Exist = false;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Console.WriteLine("enter your string");
            String Hello = Console.ReadLine();
            string pathToFile = "Path";
            foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile))
            {
                sb.Append(line);
                if (line.Contains(Hello))
                    Exist = true;
                sb.Append("\n");
            }
            if (Exist)
            {
                StringBuilder newSb = new StringBuilder();
                newSb.Append("-------------------\n");
                newSb.Append(Hello + "\n");
                newSb.Append("-------------------\n");
                StringBuilder text = newSb.Append(sb);
                File.WriteAllText(pathToFile, text.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("done");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("word not found!");

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

P.S the above code is case sensitive.

Comment: A+ well done James